# Asual Jquery Address plugin - issue on Google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, mapping, jquery-address

I have recently used the [Asual Jquery Address v.1.3](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) and it workes successfully with Firefox but I found the following problem in the Chrome:
it can't fire the ExternalChangeFunction envent and there is no alternative from using this event because document.ready fires again when trying to change the address by this script plugin

```
$.address.externalChange(function(event) {
    search.showAdvancedContent();
});  


var search = {
    showAdvancedContent: function(){
    // My code
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem. For me, it turned out to be a version incompatibility: jQuery 1.3.2 and Address 1.3 work together in Ffox but not in Chrome. Upgrading to jQuery 1.4.2 resolved the issue.

Comment: thnx a lot it's working now,but it seems jquery problem with version 1.3.2 with google chrome not Asual address plugin, I tried it with the latest ver. 1.4.3 and it's working without any problems :-)

Comment: Awesome, I had a similar problem where the basic $.address.parameter method didn't work (generated an error, calling split() on a null value), upgrading to JQuery 1.4.4 did the trick (from 1.3.2). I just hope this doesn't cause problems in other areas, ;D.